# Magento jQuery file is not calling in head section on login page on server

Tags: magento-1.8

I am working on Magento 1.8 version. In login page, jQuery file is not called in head section.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try to remove any other Jquery and check then.Sometimes server restrict the no of jquery and css. or you can merge your css and js from backend.

Comment: yes i merged css and js from backend.
this page is working fine on local and demo server.
but problems is occuring on another server.